# Шторка в приложениях Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

появилась необходимость сделать нижнюю шторку в приложении Xamarin Forms, похожую на шторку в iOS Maps или в Google Maps, с возможностью растягивать её на весь экран и так же сворачивать. Ниже прикрепляю фото с примером.  Уже несколько дней не могу найти решение. Буду благодарен за любую помощь. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Наконец-то разобрался, оставлю ответ, может кому то будет полезно.
Разметка Xaml:

```
<Frame Grid.Row="{Binding GridRowMap}"
               Grid.RowSpan="{Binding GridRowSpanMap}"
               Padding="0"
               HasShadow="False"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
               IsClippedToBounds="True"
               CornerRadius="15"
               TranslationY="0"
               Margin="0,0,0,-300"
               IsVisible="{Binding VissibleMap}"
               x:Name="frameMap">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Up"
                                        Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_SwipedUp"
                                        Threshold="100"/>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Down"
                                        Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_SwipedDown"
                                        Threshold="100"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```

Cod Behind C#:

```
private bool _isExpanded = false;

    async void SwipeGestureRecognizer_SwipedUp(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SwipedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isExpanded)
        {
            await frameMap.TranslateTo(0, -300, 200, Easing.CubicInOut);
            
            _isExpanded = true;
        }
    }

    async void SwipeGestureRecognizer_SwipedDown(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SwipedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isExpanded)
        {
            await frameMap.TranslateTo(0, 0, 200, Easing.CubicInOut);
            _isExpanded = false;
            
        }
    }
```